# How to socket.io with express generator? Individual socket, for individual link

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have typical express-generator app. In my controllers folder I have code:

```
        router.get('/:id([A-Za-z0-9_]{5,25})', function(req, res, next) {
            res.render('my-page.html', { title: 'Messages'});
             //How to implement socket.io code for this page?
            /*
             io.on('connection', function(socket){
                 console.log('a user connected');
             });
           */
        });
```

I tried simple guide from socket.io website and from stackoverflow advices, but it isn't working.
Try to imagine, that here is many different chat rooms, and for every room, I need to open individual socket... I know how to make it global, but have no idea, how to make personal socket, for personal page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what rooms are made for.

```
 socket.join(<ROOM_NAME>)
```

If you'd like to join a room, named for URL you got connected from, you can use `socket.request.url`. For instance:

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => 
  {
    const _req = socket.request
    console.log(_req.url) // do something with it
  }
```

#### edit

and do not put socket.io logic in your REST route. Make one, global connection logic, which you can (obviously) make modular.